# date tick become number after set x scale to 'linear'

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(
    index_value_hist_funddb_df['date'], 
    index_value_hist_funddb_df['value'], 
  )
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.yscale('log')
```

The normal chart:

[image: the normal chart]
It works fine, until I accidently add a line of "plt.xscale('linear')" to the end. Like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(
    index_value_hist_funddb_df['date'], 
    index_value_hist_funddb_df['value'], 
  )
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('linear') # Here is the change.
```

Chart with xscale set to linear:

[image: chart with xscale set to linear]

Now the tick of x axis becomes number.

The default setting of xscale is linear according to matplotlib document, so how this happened if I set "linear" obviously?